# No ReactJS, é possível garantir que um método da classe só seja executada após o setState ser concluído?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, front-end, react

Estou fazendo um [projeto do FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/build-a-camper-leaderboard) usando ReactJS. Ele consiste em fazer dois *Leaderboards*: um dos *campers* com maior pontuação nos últimos 30 dias e outro dos que acumularam mais pontos, onde no site será exibido um deles por vez, o usuário pode escolher qual *leaderboard* deseja ver no momento. Fiz a troca ser possível por meio do clique no elemento de título da tabela. Porém, estou enfrentando problemas devido o `setState()` ser assíncrono.

Atualmente é necessário clicar 2x para que a tabela mude, ao invés de uma só. Usei alguns `consoles.log` pra depurar e acredito que o método que criei para gerenciar o *fetch* `getFetch()` esteja sendo executado antes do estado ser alterado.

E gostaria de saber, se é possível garantir que o método `getFetch()` só seja executado após o `setState` ser concluído?

Já tentei usar *async/await* e *callback*, mas não funcionou. Além disso já busquei por soluções na documentação e em outros sites, mas nenhuma sugerida deu certo (ou foi eu que não consegui implementar).

### Segue o trecho de código onde o state é alterado e o [link do preview](https://codepen.io/daniellycosta/full/QaPZXy/)

```
const allTimeApi ='https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime'
const recentApi = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent'

class TableContent extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   allTimeRequested:false,
   usersData:[],
  }};

 getFetch(){
  fetch(this.state.allTimeRequested? allTimeApi : recentApi)
   .then(results => results.json())
   .then(data => {
     let tableData = data.map((user,index)=>(
      <tr key={user.username} style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <th>{index+1}</th>
        <td>
          <img 
            src={user.img}
            className="profilePhotos" 
            alt={`${user.username} profile photo`}/>
          <a 
           href={`https://www.freecodecamp.com/${user.username}`}>
           {user.username}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{user.recent}</td>
        <td>{user.alltime}</td>
      </tr>
      ))
      this.setState({
        usersData: tableData,
      })
  })
 }

 /*Gostaria de fazer o getFetch ser exec após o setState nos dois métodos abaixo*/

 showBestRecent = () => {
  this.setState({allTimeRequested:false})
  this.getFetch()
 }

 showBestAllTime = () => {
  this.setState({allTimeRequested:true})
  this.getFetch()
 }

 componentDidMount(){
  this.getFetch()
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div className="col-12" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
    <table className="table table-striped table-bordered tableShadow">
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Camper name</th>

      <th 
       className={this.state.allTimeRequested? 
       "notSelected":"selected grad"}
       onClick={this.showBestRecent}>Points in past 30 days</th>

      <th 
       className={this.state.allTimeRequested?
       "selected grad":"notSelected"} 
       onClick={this.showBestAllTime}>All time points</th>

     <tbody>
      {this.state.usersData}
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   )} 
 }
```

### Soluções Tentadas:

#### Async/await:

Ao fazer isso, nada é renderizado na tela, tentei de duas formas

forma 1:

```
 showBestRecent = async () => {
  await this.setState({allTimeRequested:false})
  this.getFetch()
 }
```

forma 2:

```
showBestRecent = async () => {
 await this.setState({allTimeRequested:false})
.then(this.getFetch())
}
```

#### callback:

Ao fazer isso, o state muda (percebo por causa da mudança de style no elemento do header da tabela) mas é como se a função getFetch não fosse executada (a tabela não muda)

```
 showBestRecent = () => {
  this.setState({allTimeRequested:false}),
  () => this.getFetch()
 }
```

*Se cometi algum erro grotesco, peço desculpas. Ainda sou iniciante em JS e React*

Answer (score 1):

Perguntei no grupo do FreeCodeCamp da minha cidade e obtive uma resposta que funcionou. Fiquei na dúvida se devo excluir a pergunta ou não, mas pensei que alguém pudesse querer saber. Enfim, fiz o callback errado.

#### Forma Correta

```
showBestRecent = () => {
 this.setState({allTimeRequested:false},()=>this.getFetch())
}
```

*Não havia passado a função como parâmetro do `setState()`*

Comment: Sim, está correto. O segundo parâmetro do método `setState()` é uma callback para ser executada depois que o estado for atualizado.